# Force Cloce - fatal exception main java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: android, mysql

I made a listview that show detail from database. I'm using mysql here. The app doesn't build at all, it's force close when I debug the app. this is the logcat :

```
    12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.example.logreg.customer.model.MainActivity.populateListView(MainActivity.java:183)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.example.logreg.customer.model.MainActivity.access$6(MainActivity.java:181)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.example.logreg.customer.model.MainActivity$MainActivityAsync$1.run(MainActivity.java:252)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4644)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.example.logreg.customer.model.MainActivity$MainActivityAsync.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:249)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.example.logreg.customer.model.MainActivity$MainActivityAsync.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-14 06:15:41.976: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the main activity :

```
private class MainActivityAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("retrieving...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(params[0] == "delete"){
                serverRequest.sendGetRequest(ServerRequest.urlDelete+"?kode_cust="+selectedList.getKodeCust().toString());
            }else{
                /** Mengirimkan request ke server dan memproses JSON response */ 
                String response = serverRequest.sendGetRequest(ServerRequest.urlSelectAll);
                list = processResponse(response);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {              
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    populateListView();
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

and here is the populateview :

```
private void populateListView(){
        adapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos, long id) {
                if(actionMode != null){
                    return false;
                }
                actionMode = startActionMode(amCallback);
                v.setSelected(true);
                selectedList = (Customer) adapter.getItem(pos);
                return true;
            }

        });


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos,
                    long id) {
                selectedList = (Customer) adapter.getItem(pos);
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailCustomer.class);
                in.putExtra("kode_cust", selectedList.getKodeCust().toString());
                in.putExtra("nama_cust", selectedList.getNamaCust());
                in.putExtra("contact_person_cust", selectedList.getContactPerson());
                in.putExtra("alm_cust", selectedList.getAlmtCust());
                in.putExtra("wilayah_cust", selectedList.getWilCust());
                in.putExtra("telp_cust", selectedList.getTelpCust());
                in.putExtra("hp_cust", selectedList.getHpCust());
                in.putExtra("fax_cust", selectedList.getFaxCust());
                in.putExtra("email_cust", selectedList.getEmailCust());
                in.putExtra("limit_cust", selectedList.getLimitCust().toString());

                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
       }
```

is there something wrong with my populateview code or there are code that I haven't input in there? because in the beginning it can work, but after I made it in new project android in eclipse, it shows that problems above.

Comment: Your `listView` is most probably `NULL`. Check if you instantiate `listView` after `populateListView` call.

Comment: @Foxinsocks this is line 183 'listView.setAdapter(adapter)'

Comment: @MoppyMoppy so listView == null.

Comment: but I already set : 'adapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);'

Answer (score 0):

The only way your code can throw a null pointer exception in that method, and with that stack trace, is if `listView` is null when the method is called. You need to look at how and where you're initialising `listView`.

There are other parts of the method that could throw such an exception, but they are inside inner classes, and if the exception were being thrown there, then those methods would show up in the stack trace.

Comment: could you please show me the example of exception you mean?

Comment: @MoppyMoppy I mean that it's going wrong on the line `listView.setAdapter(adapter)`, because `listView` is null, and it's illegal to try to call a method on a null instance.

Comment: could you please tell me what should I do to correct it? before, I using the same code and try to call that method, there was nothing error and could work perfectly..

Comment: this just happen when I made other project and using the same code (copy paste) when I run th first project, it can be work perfectly fine. I Just change the name of adapter class.